# AdControl in windows phone 7

Tags: windows-phone-7, ads, windows-phone, windows-phone-7-emulator

We are planning to use AdControl in our windows phone app to show advertisement.

But we have some doubts,

Is the ads shown in Adcontrol is given by the microsoft ?.

We want to use a openx link to show ads. Is it possible to set openx link to the AdControl ?

Thnks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use the AdControl that is part of the WP7 the ads are served to your app by [Microsoft's Pubcenter](https://pubcenter.microsoft.com). AdControl does not allow the client injecting additional ads into the AdControl.

If you want to vary how the ads are served, you will have to build your ad control. Have a look at [AdRotator](http://wp7adrotator.codeplex.com) that supports a bunch or ad providers. WP7 also does not support arbitrary flash rendering, which OpenX appears to use.